# Syntax for changing a label color at github via the github API

Tags: html, bash, curl, github, label

I have a bash script that (I cribbed via stackoverflow) that adds labels thusly

```
curl --user "$USER:$PASS" --include --request POST --data '{"name":"priority:Blocking","color":"ff0000"}' "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/labels"
```

Works fine.  Now I want to change the color of some of the labels.  I looked here: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/#update-a-label.  So I tried

```
curl --user "$USER:$PASS" --include --request PATCH --data '{"name":"type:Feature","color":"d9d2e9"}' "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/labels"
```

But github responds

```
{
"message": "Not Found",
"documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

I can't figure out how to translate github's examples into a curl-based call.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A kindly support person at github provided the answer:

```
 curl --user "$USER:$PASS" "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/labels/type:Bug" -X PATCH -d '{"name":"type:Bug","color":"674ea7"}'
```

It seems odd that one has to provide the "name" twice, but it works like a charm.

$USER and $PASS are of course one's github username and password. $REPO has to be the full name of the repo, e.g. mygithubname/myrepo